# Add ten numbers using only two variables and a loop

Tags: c++

So, I used following code but my friends say this code is incorrect as I am using third variable in for-loop. Kindly help.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  cin >> y;
  x = x + y;
}
cout << x;
```

Comment: Your friends are *yanking your chain*

Comment: I am teaching assistant for OOP instructor so you can see my reputation is on the line. :P

Comment: are there any restrictions on the size of the numbers being added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no rules restricting the types of variables, so you could just use an array and do it in *one* variable:

```
int arr[3] = {0};
for (; arr[0] < 10; ++arr) {
  cin >> arr[1];
  arr[2] += arr[1];
}
cout << arr[2];
```

However, you could also do it using a recursive function using two variables (if you consider the function argument a variable); this doesn't even need a loop (though I'm not sure if the `and a loop` part means that you *have* to use a loop, in which case you could of course just put a sneaky `do { ... } while(0);` somewhere. ;-)

```
int sum(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int v;
    cin >> v;
    return v + sum(x - 1);
}

cout << sum(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought of using recursion too but the "loop" is a real restriction. There must be a loop that runs 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

I see nothing wrong with this code. More descriptive variables would be more helpful maybe (i.e. `y` -> `userInput`, `x` -> `sum`).

Comment: Yes. that's what I meant. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Rationale:

Use a 64-bit value as the accumulator since it's unlikely that users will enter numbers that large.

Use the top 8 bits (could be 4) of the accumulator as the counter.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int64_t accum = int64_t { 10 } << 56;
    while (accum & (int64_t{0xff} << 56))
    {
        int next;
        cin >> next;
        accum += next;
        accum -= int64_t { 1 } << 56;
    }

    cout << accum << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can restrict the range of the sum, you can do something like

```
const unsigned LIMIT = 1000000;

unsigned x;
for ( x = LIMIT * 10; x >= LIMIT; x -= LIMIT) 
{
  unsigned y;
  cin >> y;
  x += y;
}
cout << x;
```

This would be an arithmetic equivalent of other bit-fiddling tricks based on squeezing two values into one variable, as in @Richard Hodges's answer.

But that requires restricting the range of the sum.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you want to use this `x += y;` . This is a two-variable inside a loop method that does the same functionality as `x = x + y;` that they considered a three-variables inside a loop.

Comment: Two int variables in general. You can use in any way.

Comment: I don't see why you considered your code as three variables?

Comment: I am not really doing it. Whatever I do my friends shoot it down saying I did that or something. I think they are just overcomplicating this programming 101 question.